# Hibernate LazyInitializationException only during refresh

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Long time reader, first time asker, so please be gentle. :) I'm using Hibernate as my JPA 2.0 provider (*hibernate-core-4.1.16*, *hibernate-jpa-1.0.1*) and I'm having trouble with something seemingly simple.

### Short Version

I have two entities *A* and *B*, where *A* holds a list of *B*. Every time a new list of *B* is set, I want to process it. Hence I put the processing inside the setter for the list. The same setter is used by Hibernate.

This works fine for loading instances of *A* from the database and even refreshing works when it is not cascaded. But as soon as I enable *CascadeType.REFRESH* and do a refresh, accessing the new list of *B* inside the setter, causes the infamous *LazyInitializationException*.

I have tried some things (see below) but nothing helped and I'm out of ideas. :(

### Long Version

I created a minimal working example to show what is supposed to happen and what actually happens.

#### Classes

**Note:** I omitted the id-attributes. (In case this is important: the id-getters are annotated with `@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`.)

Class *A*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tableA")
public class A {

    private List<B> bar;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "theA", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<B> getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    private void setBar(List<B> bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
        System.out.println("Number of Bs during set: " + bar.size());
    }
}
```

Class *B*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tableB")
public class B {

    private A theA;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", nullable = false)
    public A getTheA() {
        return theA;
    }

    private void setTheA(A theA) {
        this.theA = theA;
    }
}
```

#### Data

The two tables *tableA* and *tableB* each contain one row, so there will be one instance of *A* which holds one instance of *B*.

#### Execution

Finally, this is the executed code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TestDBManager").createEntityManager();
    A theA = (A) em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM A a").getResultList().get(0);
    System.out.println("Number of Bs after load: " + theA.getBar().size());
    em.refresh(theA);
    System.out.println("Number of Bs after refresh: " + theA.getBar().size());
}
```

#### What Should Happen vs. What Actually Happens

This is the expected outcome

```
Number of Bs during set: 1
Number of Bs after load: 1
Number of Bs during set: 1
Number of Bs after refresh: 1
```

But in fact this happens:

```
Number of Bs during set: 1
Number of Bs after load: 1
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Exception occurred inside setter of isi.power.core.test.A.bar
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1377)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.refresh(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:939)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.refresh(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:906)
    at line of call to refresh
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Exception occurred inside setter of isi.power.core.test.A.bar
    ... many more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    ... many more
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection, no session or session was closed
    ... many more
```

### What I Tried

#### Don't Touch the List

If I remove the calls to the list inside the setter, Hibernate finishes its magic after calling `setBar` and I get no exception, when it is called later (after the `refresh`-call in `main`). But I loose the possibility to process the list inside the setter, which I'd rather not.

#### Don't Cascade Refresh

The problem goes away if I do not cascade refreshes, i.e. if I replace

```
cascade = CascadeType.ALL
```

with

```
cascade = { CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE }
```

Since I mostly do this for the refresh, this is not an option.

#### Fetch Eagerly

I added `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` to the `@OneToMany`-annotation. Same exception...

#### Transaction

I surrounded the load and refresh calls with `em.getTransaction().begin();` and `em.getTransaction().commit();` . Same exception...

#### Hibernate.initialize

I tried to call `Hibernate.initialize` inside the setter which leads to a different exception:

```
Number of Bs during set: 1
Number of Bs after load: 1
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Exception occurred inside setter of isi.power.core.test.A.bar
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1377)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.refresh(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:939)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.refresh(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:906)
    at line of call to refresh
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Exception occurred inside setter of isi.power.core.test.A.bar
    ... many more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    ... many more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: force initialize loading collection
    ... many more
```

### Long Story Short

I'm fresh out of ideas... I'd be very thankful for any pointer to a possible solution of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Field Access** if that is acceptable (that is - annotate the **field**, not the *method*).

E.g.:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "tableA")
public class A {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "theA", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<B> bar;

    public List<B> getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    private void setBar(List<B> bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
        System.out.println("Number of Bs during set: " + bar.size());
    }
}
```

Prepared a simple project with your example classes - and it worked with field access.

---

*But* if there is a need to do the processing **also** during refresh, than probably you can look at    using **@PostLoad** method, e.g.:

```java
@PostLoad
public void processB() {
    System.out.println("Number of Bs after load/refresh: " + this.bar.size());
}
```

Full example will look something like this (this way it should work both when the setter gets called manually withing the code and automatically within load/refresh of an entity):

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "tableA")
public class A {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "theA", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<B> bar;

    public List<B> getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(List<B> bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
        processBar();
    }

    @PostLoad
    public void processBar() {
        System.out.println("Number of Bs after load/refresh: " + this.bar.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :) **Field Access** would be acceptable, but then - of course - the setter doesn't get called. I had high hopes for `@PostLoad` but it produces exactly the same exception in both scenarios. Did it work for you?

Comment: It worked for me with hibernate-core 4.1.12 (I can't find the 4.1.16 version that you mentioned).

I used FIELD access *with* @PostLoad.



There is related question with PostLoad where 2 bugs are mentioned (but seems that they were fixed)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973291/reading-a-set-in-postload-on-jpa-hibernate

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example of @PostLoad that should work for both manual calls to setter and load/refresh support.

Comment: I also went after `@PostLoad` and found two other SO-posts about this. The [answer to the one you linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6974814/2525313) marks this as a bug. The [bug was filed long ago](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6043) and resolved in _Hibernate 4.1.8_. The `@PostLoad`-approach works now and I can set in a way that fits my purpose. :) Thanks! (Unfortunately, I can't upvote this answer due to my questionable reputation.)